# Google Sheets - How to sum columns in a query formula based off different drop down filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm brand new to google sheets and have been trying for a couple days to get this to work. I currently am using a query to pull my data from the school data tab then using drop down menus to look at the data by school and in between a window of dates. I'm trying to get it so when I change the window of dates of the school that and will produce a sum of that column at the bottom of each column for the dates and school i have selected that will change with whatever I have picked in the drop downs. Following different tutorials keeps giving me the same problem, that being when I add the sum query it will add up the whole column and doesn't change based on the school selected. Would really appreciate any help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zd3nvo5EpY-8Qh_ElEv5JuiuF7vwvNsQXdpdfvt_Rmw/edit#gid=1096123326

Comment: Can you add an example of the result you are looking for? It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: I just added an extra sheet so you can see on sheet4. The far right table is what i'm looking for, so when my filters change (date, School) The total at the bottom will change with it but across the row

Comment: I'm new to all this so sorry if I haven't explained it well. What I'm looking for is there to be a total of the columns but only based off of what filters I have picked. So, if I pick a date range and school I only want it to return data for date range and school then at the bottom I'd like it to sum up whatever data is showing. Currently the filtering works fine but I can't get a total sum at the bottom that changes dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your sheet to reflect this solution:

In `School Data` column `W`, I changed the formula in `W2` to

```js
=arrayformula(if(len('School Data'!A2:A),mmult(n('School Data'!C2:R),transpose(sign(column('School Data'!C:R)))),))
```

This sums up all the needed rows.

Then, I edited your `QUERY` formula in `Sheet2` cell `B11`:

```js
=query('School Data'!A1:AL999,"SELECT V, W 
where V is not null 
AND V >= date """&text(C6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND V <= date """&text(C7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND A ="""&F6&""" 
LABEL W 'Total # of Phone Contacts Attempted'")
```

I simply replaced your `SUM()` selections with column W, which already takes all the sums.

[image]

---

Summing all the columns in the query:

```js
={query('School Data'!A1:AL999,"SELECT V, SUM(C), SUM(D), SUM(E), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K), SUM(L), SUM(M), SUM(N), SUM(O), SUM(P), SUM(Q), SUM(R) 
where V is not null 
AND V >= date """&text(C6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND V <= date """&text(C7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND A ="""&F6&"""GROUP BY V 
LABEL SUM(C) 'Total # of Phone Contacts Attempted'");"Total",query('School Data'!A1:AL999,"SELECT SUM(C), SUM(D), SUM(E), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K), SUM(L), SUM(M), SUM(N), SUM(O), SUM(P), SUM(Q), SUM(R) 
where V is not null 
AND V >= date """&text(C6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND V <= date """&text(C7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" 
AND A ="""&F6&""" 
LABEL SUM(C) '', SUM(D) '',SUM(E) '',SUM(F) '',SUM(G) '',SUM(H) '',SUM(I) '',SUM(J) '',SUM(K) '',SUM(L) '',SUM(M) '',SUM(N) '',SUM(O) '',SUM(P) '',SUM(Q) '',SUM(R) ''")}
```

[image: ex2]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It's greatly appreciated that you would even look at my issue at all and try to help. I may not be following correctly but I need a sum of the columns not the row. So I need to know how much of each column they did on that day and the the sum of that column for that timeframe and school.

Comment: ohhh okay, I think I understand now. I will let you know once I edit my answer :)

Comment: @oarsa5 my answer has been updated, as well as your sheet

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That's exactly what I was looking for. Can't thank you enough

Comment: Of course! Happy to help. Make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)